# Lockdown Command does not lock channels?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So this is a lockdown comman and the command works fine without errors but once I do !lockdown I get the messages saying that its locked but people can still type, if someone could help

My Code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const ms = require("ms")

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    if(!client.lockit) client.lockit = [];
    let time = args.join(' ');
    let validUnlocks = ['relase', 'unlock'];
    if(!time) return message.channel.send('You must set a duration for the lockdown!')

    if(validUnlocks.includes(time)) {
        message.channel.overwritePermissions(message.guild.id, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: false
        }).then(() => {
            message.channel.sendMessage('Lockdown has been lifted!');
            clearTimeout(client.lockit[message.channel.id]);
            delete client.lockit[message.channel.id];
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    } else {
        message.channel.overwritePermissions(message.guild.id, {
            SEND_MESSAGES: false
        }).then(() => {
            message.channel.sendMessage(`Channel Locked for ${ms(ms(time), { long:true})}`).then(() => {
                client.lockit[message.channel.id] = setTimeout(() => {
                    message.channel.overwritePermissions(message.guild.id, {
                        SEND_MESSAGES: false
                    }).then(message.channel.sendMessage('Lockdown Lifted')).catch(console.error);
                    delete client.lockit[message.channel.id];
                }, ms(time));
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
        })
    }
}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "lockdown",
    description: "Lock a channel",
    usage: "lockdown <duration>",
    accessableby: "Moderators",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your code change permission for the `@everyone` role.

If you have another role, with higher hierarchy level, and have permission `SEND_MESSAGES`, they can still type in that channel. It may be the answer, but since I don't know the structure of your server. I cannot say for sure.